# Why is the "this" keyword used in Constructor and Setters?

Tags: java, constructor, setter, getter

A constructor is used to initialize a value and assign it to the class variable in the time of creating the class instance, right?

```
public class Joke{
   private String jokeSetup;
   private String jokePunchLine;

   public Joke(String jokeSetup , String jokePunchLine){
       this.jokeSetup=jokeSetup;
       this.jokePunchLine=jokePunchLine;
   }
}
```

Consider the following:

```
public Joke(String jokeSetup , String jokePunchLine)
```

Is another variable with same name created?

If so, why are they assigned to the former `jokeSetup` and `jokePunchLine` values?

PS:This code is not created by me.It was shown in the videos from which I am learning Java.

Answer (score 7):

The purpose of a constructor is to initialize the object that was just created, for instance by filling in its *instance fields* (also called *instance variables*). `this` is used in your constructor to refer to the instance the constructor is initializing.

In your example constructor, you have *parameters* and *instance fields*. The constructor is taking the values of the parameters and assigning those values to the instance fields:

```
public Joke(String jokeSetup , String jokePunchLine)
//          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---- Declares parameters this
//                                                      constructor accepts when
//                                                      called
{
//                 vvvvvvvvv------------ parameter
    this.jokeSetup=jokeSetup;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---------------------- instance field

//                     vvvvvvvvvvvvv---- parameter
    this.jokePunchLine=jokePunchLine;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^------------------ instance field
}
```

The constructor could initialize instance fields with constant values instead, or by using a parameter value indirectly (for instance, looking something up), etc. It's not always a direct one-to-one assignment as it is in your example.

In your example, the parameters have the same names as the instance fields, but that's not a requirement. For instance, this constructor does exactly the same thing as yours:

```
public Joke(String theJokeSetup , String theJokePunchLine)
//                 ^---------------------^---------- Note the name changes
{
//                   vvvvvvvvvvvv------------ parameter
    this.jokeSetup = theJokeSetup;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------------------------- instance field

//                       vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---- parameter
    this.jokePunchLine = theJokePunchLine;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------------------- instance field
}
```

---

Java lets you leave off the `this.` part when referring to an instance field and just use the field name on its own (e.g. `jokeSetup` instead of `this.jokeSetup`). You can't do that in your constructor unless you rename the parameters, though, because they have the same names as the instance fields, so `jokeSetup` in your constructor is the parameter, not the field. When there's a conflict like that, the *most local* identifier takes precedence (in your constructor, the parameter is the most local).

When there's no conflict, it's a matter of style whether you use the `this.` part or not. (I always use `this.`, I find it clearer.) So for instance, here's another version of that constructor which does exactly the same thing as your original:

```
public Joke(String theJokeSetup , String theJokePunchLine)
//                 ^---------------------^---------- Note the name changes
{
//              vvvvvvvvvvvv------------ parameter
    jokeSetup = theJokeSetup;
//  ^^^^^^^^^--------------------------- instance field

//                  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv---- parameter
    jokePunchLine = theJokePunchLine;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^----------------------- instance field
}
```

I mention this because, again, when there's no conflict, it's a matter of style, and you'll see this style used sometimes.

Comment: so does that mean,four variables have been created??and also,can a variable have the same name of another variable??

Comment: @Hanneeth: As I said in the answer, during the call to the constructor, there are two parameters (which aren't variables, but they're *very much like* variables) and two "instance fields" (also called "instance variables"), which are part of the instance (object). Fields are like variables in that they hold values in the same way variables do, but they're not like variables because they're tied to an object, not a scope like local variables (and parameters). *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* Once the call to the constructor is complete, the scope for that call goes away, and so do the parameters -- but the fields remain as long as the object exists.

Comment: @Hanneeth: *"can a variable have the same name of another variable"* We're getting pretty far from the original question. If we don't include instance fields as "variables," you can't have two variables with the same name in the same scope. If you have two nested scopes and they each define a variable called `x`, the *most local* one is the one you'll access when using `x`. If we include instance fields in "variables," and if we treat the instance as a scope in which its constructors and methods are nested, then you still can't define two "variables" with... *(cont'd)*

Comment: *(continuing)* ...the same name in the same scope, but you can access an instance field "variable" even if it's shadowed by a more-local variable because you have the ability to qualify your reference using `this.`.

Answer (score 2):

The class has a *field* named jokeSetup.
The method has a parameter of the same name that *shadows* that field.

So in essence there are two variables with the same name.

Using *this* makes it possible to again differentiate the *two* different usages of the same name, as *this.whatever* always denotes the corresponding field.

And you nailed it: shadowing is actually not a good idea. But this "pattern" is actually very common in Java. You could avoid it by giving the parameter a different name, such as _jokeSetup, but deviating from common practices is also bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

A parametrized constructor can be used to initialize value to the variables in the time of creating it. When the parameters and variable names are same then in this case to differentiate between both, we use **this** keyword. **This** keyworord always refer to local variable of the method or class.

Answer (score 1):

Java has an implied *context* for symbol names; the class instance (ie `this`) for non-static contexts and the class (eg `Joke`) for static.

This lets you omit the context when there is no conflict for the symbol name. For example

```
public String getJokeSetup() {
    return jokeSetup; // no "this." required, it's implied
}
```

---

When there is a conflict for the name such as the case with a method argument named the same as a field, you need to explicitly define the context, eg

```
public void setJokeSetup(final String jokeSetup) {
    // you must prefix the field with "this." to differentiate it from the argument
    this.jokeSetup = jokeSetup; 
}
```

---

Finally, here's an example that avoids a symbol name conflict

```
public void setJokeSetup(final String js) {
    jokeSetup = js;
}
```

It is fairly typical to name arguments the same as the fields they correspond to but you're certainly not constricted to such a convention.